# How to beat the last level of Clustertruck without abilities?

Tags: achievements, xbox-one, clustertruck

I just remembered this one achievement that I could never get, and it's now nagging me for some reason, so I come here searching for tips and tricks.

For the achievement you have to beat the entire main game of Clustertruck *without using abilities*. IIRC, I'm on the last level (9-10?) but I could never get it done. Any tips, tricks, and walkthrough videos are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tutorial for the final boss, it exploits a shortcut that involves jumping on a truck just after pressing the green button:

Note that there's a glitch on 9-10 where the final button press will freeze your game. For some reason, equipping an ability but not using it will keep your game from freezing. Just as long as you don't actually use any of the abilities during the level, the achievement will unlock.

Source, [Trueachivements](https://www.trueachievements.com/a224415/beat-the-game-without-abilities-achievement).